# простой скрипт на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x

Может для програмиста вопрос простой но все таки:
Есть такой скрипт:

```py
import datetime
filename = datetime.datetime.now()

def create_file():
    with open(filename.strftime("%d %B %Y")+".txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("")

create_file()
```

Он создает пустое имя файла с текущей датой. Как сделать чтобы он создавался не там где запускается а по определенном пути.
Спасибо

Comment: Первый аргумент функции `open()` — это путь. Вы указываете только имя файла, оно расценивается как относительный путь.

Comment: Нужно сделать переменную пути?

Comment: Или как добавить туда путь?

Answer (score 2):

Смена каталога в питоне:

```
import os
os.chdir('/tmp/')
```

или добавить путь к имени файла

```
filename = datetime.datetime.now()
filename = os.path.join('/tmp',filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Первый аргумент функции `open()` — это путь.
Можно указывать как относительные, так и абсолютные пути.

Вы указываете только имя файла, оно расценивается как относительный путь.
Документ будет сохранён в рабочем каталоге.

***Пример с абсолютным путём:***

```py
...
with open('C:/Users/Username/' + filename.strftime("%d %B %Y")+".txt", "w") as file:
    ...
...
```

Код выше сохранит документ в каталоге `C:/Users/Username/`.

Comment: А как удалить файлы старше 15 мин?

Comment: @rusdev1989 Что значит старше? По дате создания или изменения?

Comment: Или по имени файла?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте стандартные средства, для простого решения.

```
path= r'path/to/file' //(либо: 'path//to//file')
with open(path + filename.strftime("%d %B %Y")+".txt", "w") as f:
```

Либо ссылку на файл, как в переменной path.

```
with open( r'path/to/file'+ filename.strftime("%d %B %Y")+".txt", "w") as f:
```

А грамотнее использовать средства питона модуль os(import os). Подробнее на сайтах читайте: [Модуль ОС](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-os.html)